# Searcheable Select like Chosen with size=10

Tags: jquery, html

I have seen JQuery [Chosen](http://plugins.jquery.com/chosen/), which looks good. I look for something similar which shows a fixed number of entries, say 10 entries, and does not close.

I have been trying with `on("chosen:ready", sendTriggerChosenOpen)`, and it fires, but as soon as you click out of the box it closes. And it is non-trivial to have the input field active on page-load.

Obviously `Chosen` is for a self-hiding list.

Is there an alternative with a similar look-and-feel, just with behaviour like a multi-select and with an input-field which is activateable on page load?

A dropdown-menu with integrated searchbar would also do the job, it just has to be optically integrated (I don't want to imitate the built-in css).

Comment: can you illustrate with an example on JSFiddle?  You will probably get a better response with that.

Comment: @wrschneider99, I can't get chosen lib into jsfiddle, but maybe http://jsfiddle.net/x6osavpn/2 helps.

Comment: are you using version 1.4.1 ?

Comment: @Tim: Oh, I didn't look before, it is version 1.0.0. I will check the new version.

Comment: @flaschenpost okay. I have one question, do you want the field to be still collapse after the user selected one item ?

Comment: In my primary usecase the page should fire "commit' when a select has been made, but in general I think a completely non-collapsing version (like "size=10" in classic multiselect) is the missing thing.

Comment: allright. I have found a solution for you. Sadly this requires a bit of modifying the Chosen - sourcecode but it will do the trick for now ;)

Comment: @flaschenpost please note that I am assuming that you are now using version 1.4.x (it might be work for older versions aswell but I didn't test that)

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Ok, what you want can't be achieved using select2 or chosen without going through a alot of changes.

Using your example with a code to check for the inserted text in the `input` you can filter your options like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#search').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#term').find('option:not(:contains(' + this.value + '))').hide();
        $('#term').find('option:contains(' + this.value + ')').show();
    });
});
```

working fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/x6osavpn/3/

**EDIT 2**

And check if pressed key is `enter` to select first `option` and focus on the `select`.

```
if(e.keyCode==13){
    $('#term').focus();
    $("#term").val($("#term option:first").val());
}else{
    /* what we already had */
}
```

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x6osavpn/4/

**OLD ANSWER**

I think [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) will work for what you want (if i get you right).

You have options to select multiple values and to have search bar included among other options.

Comment: Thanks, select2 is also a nice thing, but it also is not "opened" and in this case I need single choice. See the http://jsfiddle.net/x6osavpn/2/.

Comment: Thanks, select2 is also a nice thing, but it also is not "opened" and in this case I need single choice. See the http://jsfiddle.net/x6osavpn/2/. I know it is not that hard to write yourself, but then all the browsertesting and updating stays in-house too. So I wonder if my goal is really so special (a short time ago it seemed standard to me).

Comment: check if this solution suits your needs

Comment: Thanks for all the work, but I just don't want to go down to keyup and keycode 13, different browsers and mobile versions and the like smell like trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using select2, this is straightforward. [Here is a fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/1151/), it comes down to:

```
var selector = $("#term");

selector.select2();
selector.on("select2:close", function (e) {
    selector.select2('open');
});

selector.select2('open');
```

Comment: I didn't get select2 to work in my bootstrap-page yet, but it is the simplest and best working fiddle - chosen.js seems to lack `open()` completely.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution which requires some editing inside the chosen.js .
This solution is not elegant at all but it somehow works. I will try to improve it by adding a `.toPermament()` option as soon as I find the time to do so. 
First open chosen.jquery.js and search for `Chosen.prototype.close_field` .
Since we don't ever want to close the field there is no need for most of this function. Comment it out like this:

```
Chosen.prototype.close_field = function() {
 /*
  $(this.container[0].ownerDocument).unbind("click.chosen", this.click_test_action);
  this.active_field = false;
  this.results_hide();
  this.container.removeClass("chosen-container-active"); */
  this.clear_backstroke(); 
  this.show_search_field_default();
  return this.search_field_scale();  
};
```

Next one is `Chosen.prototype.results_hide` . This one is completely useless now, but called at many places from within Chosen, so instead of just cutting it away we will do a little replacement here. Change the function like this:

```
Chosen.prototype.results_hide = function() {
     /* if (this.results_showing) {
    this.result_clear_highlight();
    this.container.removeClass("chosen-with-drop");
    this.form_field_jq.trigger("chosen:hiding_dropdown", {
      chosen: this
    });
      }
      return this.results_showing = false; */
      this.results_show();
    };
```

So instead of hiding the results we now made sure that they will be always shown. 
Last modification is needed for submitting. If the user presses *Enter* the current values of the dropdown selection will not be reset. In order to reset he would have to doubleclick the current selection. 
Search for `Chosen.prototype.keydown_checker` . Inside the switch-case of this function add

```
this.result_select("");
```

right beneath `case 13:` which is the Keycode for `Enter`.
It should look like this now:

```
case 13:
      this.result_select(""); 
      if (this.results_showing) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      }
      break;
```

Now your Chosen-select will never fully collapse. You still can chose items by clicking on them or by filter them with the search bar. Upon pressing enter the current filter will be removed.
I hope this is what you were looking for.
**Please Note:** Those are modifications which will be applied for **all** of your Chosen selects!

Comment: Thanks for the nice help anyway, it seems the behaviour that I want is not common enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `bootstrap-select`
Try to use this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-select.css">

 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script> 

    <select id="tokens" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <option>I actually am called "first"</option>
        <option>And me "second"</option>
        <option >I am "last"</option>
      </select>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/q32p1z6x/)

visit this link you will find all options here : https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Since I am working in bootstrap, that looks promising. Just that I can't get it "opened" or showing 10 items instead of 1 item, and that it should not be an multiple- select (multiple was just the way to get 10 items in "classic" html).

Comment: just remove "multiple" form here:  <select id="tokens" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true"> to make it simple select

Comment: visit this link you will find all options here : https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: It seems hard to have those components autofocused, and the input field to be active. anybody remembering those old times where a web-page rendered and the most important input field hat the focus? Just some input, tab, enter. ;-)

Comment: you may found this type of functionality in above mentioned URL ( https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#bloodhound ). i.e after pressing tab, input field will be auto filled with most promising value